# OpenGL texture no matching overload function found

Tags: opengl, textures

first of all my Code of my Fragmenshader.

```
#version 330 core
struct Material{
       sampler2D diffuse;
};

struct Light{
vec3 position;

vec3 ambient;
vec3 diffuse;

};

in  vec3 Normal;
in  vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

void main()
{
 //ambient
 vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords));
 //Diffuse
 vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
 vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
 float diff = max(dot(norm,lightDir),0.0);
 vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff *vec3(texture(material.diffuse,TexCoords));
 color = vec4(ambient+diffuse,1.0f);

 }
```

If i want to compile i get the error:
'texture': not mathcing overloaded function found (using implicit conversion)
I looked at the GLSL documentation, but i looks correct. After that i searched for an error in my OpenGL file... but i looks ok.

Comment: Does slicing off the Z coordinate of `TexCoords` using `TexCoords.xy` help?  Right now you're trying to sample a `sampler2D` with a `vec3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to read from a 2D sampler using 3D coordinates. Either change the `in vec3 TexCoords` to `in vec2 TexCoords` or change the texture lookup from `texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords)` to `texture(material.diffuse, TexCoords.xy)`

Comment: Thank you :D what a stupid mistake. In the fragshader its defined as out vec2 TexCoords....